# Error message "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code and when I run it the error is in   `new Program(int.Parse(args[0]));` and the exception is

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

My code:

```
  using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace MagicSquares
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
        new Program(int.Parse(args[0]));

        }

        private int n;
        private int constant;
        private int[,] solution;

        public Program(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
            int nSquared = n * n;
            int sumAllNumbs = nSquared * (nSquared + 1) / 2;
            constant = sumAllNumbs / n;

            int threads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Parallel.For(0, threads, (i) =>
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, nSquared).ToArray();
                int[,] square = new int[n, n];

                do
                {
                    RandomizeNumbers(rnd, numbers);
                    FillSquare(square, numbers);

                    if (IsMagicSquare(square))
                        solution = square;

                } while (solution == null);
            });

            PrintSquare(solution);
        }

        private void RandomizeNumbers(Random rnd, int[] numbers)
        {
            for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(numbers.Length);
                int temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[index];
                numbers[index] = temp;
            }
        }

        private void FillSquare(int[,] square, int[] numbers)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                {
                    square[y, x] = numbers[index];
                    index++;
                }
        }

        private bool IsMagicSquare(int[,] square)
        {
            //Check horizontal
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                    sum += square[y, x];

                if (sum != constant)
                    return false;
            }

            //Check vertical
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
                    sum += square[y, x];

                if (sum != constant)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void PrintSquare(int[,] square)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                    Console.Write(square[y, x] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this means that the process wasn't started with any command line parameters. Why not validate that there are arguments before assuming you can parse them?

Comment: Seems strange to me to create an instance of the outer `Program` class inside the `Main` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** Your error clearly tells that you are accessing the args[0] index zero element but args array has no elements.

**Solution:** you need to pass the command line arguments to your program, and also you need to make sure that there are elements before accessing the array to avoid runtime exceptions.

Try This:

```
if(args.Length > 0)
  new Program(int.Parse(args[0]));
```

You can Pass the command line arguments by one of the following way:

**Method 1 :** if you are running your application from Visual Studio you can pass the command line arguments by following steps:

1.Goto Project `Properties`
2.Select `Debug` tab
3.Enter the command line arguments in `CommanLine Arguments` textbox

**Method 2 :** if you are running your application from command line using you can pass the command line arguments by following command:

```
c:\MyPrograms\>MyApplication.exe 23
```

Comment: are you still getting te exception? if yes where exactly you are getting?

Comment: you can see my all code and no error just run and stop without do anything

Comment: you need to debug your program, i suspect that you are not passing any commandline arguments read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try  to check that args is not empty    `if(args.Length>0)`

```
class Program

         {
            static void Main(string[] args)
             {
              if(args.Length>0)
             new Program(int.Parse(args[0]));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `args` arguments are for command line arguments. You can run your program from the command prompt as `yourexe <some integer>` and you will see there will be no exception. Alternatively, from the project properties in visual studio, you can also set command line arguments to be supplied while debugging.